# How to download a private bitbucket.org repository using pure REST API calls, version 1 or 2

Tags: c#, rest, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to clone/download my private bitbucket.org repository using C#, but I want to do it using pure HTTPS REST calls, and not a third party lib, i want to learn how it works.

So far I could only find example code for version 1 of the api.
This is what i've got working so far in C#:

```
static void AUthenticate()
    {
        var time = GenerateTimeStamp();
        var url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/request_token";
        var secret = "SECRET";
        var key = "KEY";

        var sigBaseStringParams = "";
        sigBaseStringParams += "oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocal%3Fdump";
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + key;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + GetNonce();
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=" + "HMAC-SHA1";
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + time;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
        var sigBaseString = "POST&";
        sigBaseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(url) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sigBaseStringParams);

        var signature = GetSignature(sigBaseString, secret);

        var res = PostData(url, sigBaseStringParams + "&oauth_signature=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(signature));

        var items = GetParameters(res);

        var tokenSecret = items["oauth_token_secret"];
        var token = items["oauth_token"];
        var callbackConfirmed = items["oauth_callback_confirmed"];

        url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=" + token;
    }
```

This authenticates and I get 3 values back. The last URL i paste into a browser, where i grant my application access and i end up with an **oauth_verifier**

**Note:** I don't really want to do this as I am writing a server program which won't really be able to send a user to a browser link (but one thing at a time)

I then run the following code:

```
var url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/access_token";

        var token = "TOKEN FROM PREV CALL";
        var time = GenerateTimeStamp();
        var sigBaseStringParams = "";
        //sigBaseStringParams += "oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocal%3Fdump";

        var secret = "SECRET";
        var key = "KEY";

        sigBaseStringParams += "oauth_consumer_key=" + key;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_token=" + token;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + GetNonce();
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=" + "HMAC-SHA1";
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + time;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_verifier=AUTH VERIFIER FROM PREV CALL";
        var sigBaseString = "POST&";
        sigBaseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(url) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sigBaseStringParams);

        var tokenSecret = "TOKEN SECRET FROM PREVIOUS CALL";
        var signature = GetSignature(sigBaseString, secret, tokenSecret);

        var res = PostData(url, sigBaseStringParams + "&oauth_signature=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(signature));
```

This gives me a 400 bad request. I can't see much else.

I'm following the steps on this page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html#OAuthonBitbucketCloud-Refreshtokens

Why I'm doing this is because i want to eventually make a POST request (or GET) to this URL:

```
var url2 = "https://bitbucket.org/ACCOUNT/REPOSITORY/get/tip.zip?access_token="+token;
```

Because I think this will give me the entire repository in a zip file. If i put this in the browser it works because i'm logged into bitbucket.

If there is a newer/easier/better way i'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could temporarily use the 3rd party tools and see what it does using Fiddler or look at the source for the 3rd party either with actual source code or dotPeek if it isn't obfuscated.

Comment: That is one way, but how did they figure it out?
Surely the documentation should be available since it's a public api.
I'm sure i'm just looking in the wrong place or missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very simple solution.
I just had to provide credentials to a GET request:

```
 public static void Downloadfiles(string username, string password, string account, string repository, string pathToSave)
    {
        var creds = Base64Encode(String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password));

        var url = String.Format("https://bitbucket.org/{0}/{1}/get/tip.zip", account, repository);

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {

            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + creds);
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            client.DownloadFile(url, pathToSave);
        }
    }
```